# Upload videos from iPhone to YouTube

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, youtube

I have an iPhone 3GS and am trying to upload a video I shot in the Apple Camera app. Here's what I do:

- Go to the video I want to upload
- Tap "Send to YouTube"
- Enter my Gmail username and password for "YouTube password"
- I also try my old YouTube username and password

This fails and re-prompts me to enter my username and password. I don't have a YouTube password because Google merged YouTube accounts in your Google (Gmail) account.

How can I upload videos to YouTube?

Comment: Have you tried your old YouTube username and password?  I don't have Gmail and I log in with my Hotmail account.

Comment: Yes, I tried my YouTube login and that doesn't work either. Edited my post to include that info.

Comment: If your Google account was merged with your YouTube account wouldn't the password be that of your Google Account? I noticed you said you tried your YouTube password. Also you could try "forgot password" to possibly reset it.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is go directly to the Youtube app (I am testing this with my old 3GS so this should work) and drag to the left to access all of the different menus, then click on the little up arrow next to my channel (assuming you are already logged in on the app) and then you just click on the video you want to upload instead of using the photos app and 'sharing' to Youtube. You could also try logging in to Youtube on a computer as on there it should give you the option to create a new Youtube account with your Gmail assuming that the cause of the problem is that your gmail is not tied to any Youtube. Assuming it let you create a new Youtube associated with your Gmail you should just be able to go back to the app on your iPhone and try again.